# deploying the business network using hyperledger composer

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

> robert@ubuntu:~/tutoiral-network$ composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutoiral-network@0.0.1.bna
>   ⠋ Installing runtime for business network tutoiral-network@0.0.1.bna. This may t⠙ Installing runtime for business network tutoiral-network@0.0.1.bna. This may t✖ Installing runtime for business network tutoiral-network@0.0.1.bna. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Card not found: PeerAdmin@hlfv1
>   Command failed

I am trying to deploy the bna file for the first time using hyperledger composer .

Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue.

I created card and import it to wallet. Then I performed composer runtime install command and had same issue with you. 
In my case, Composer did not recognize the card imported.

Please check by composer card list command. If you can not find the card in the wallet, please repeat again from composer card create and import. You may need to delete card from wallet before importing card.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **fabric-tools** directory and run ./createPeerAdminCard.sh first before running the runtime install command. 
Your error message

> Card not found: PeerAdmin@hlfv1

means that you haven't create the PeerAdmin card.
To check all the cards you have, run command:

```
composer card list
```